# docker port mapping doesn't work

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm confused - I have Docker file which use as "FROM" https://hub.docker.com/r/consol/ubuntu-xfce-vnc/ image. It's very fast way to build vnc container with gui and chromium what is require by my project. And everything is fine but i have problem with port mapping - i want to run few similar containers on same server so it's obvious that each container must use different port. I assumed that the easiest way will be run as below:

```
docker run -p 5902:5901 -t cont1
docker run -p 5903:5901 -t cont2
docker run -p 5904:5901 -t cont3
docker run -p 5905:5901 -t cont4
```

but when i try to connect via vnc, the connection can by established only with 5901 port - despite the fact that i use -p with mapping. Maybe someone will know what's wrong?

Comment: From where did you try to connect, inside a `container` or outside `container`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the reason of my problem - I have been running my containers locally and I assume that that's was the reason - When I had moved them to external server, port mapping is ok right now! Cheers